# Outlier Detection

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, anomaly-detection, outlier

I have a dataset which has two class. It has 13 features. They are values which are sent from 13 sensors. Label is True or False. When I use mad outlier detection, when the label is false(really there are some outliers), it detects the outliers correctly. I mean for example when sensors 1 and 3 are modified which leads to having label "False", it detects 1 and 3 exactly and don't raise wrong additional sensor's number or fewer than actual one.

The problem is when the the label is True and there is no outlier. It still outputs some sensors as outlier. Actually it raise false positive. This makes hard to know that this is really outlier or not.  How can I solve this problem and finally be sure that this result is outlier or not? I have tested combination of this method with some other outlier detection results. I also used clustering in combination with MAD but I have not reached to a systematic solution.

Btw, Maybe you ask when you have label why you use outlier detection. No, I should develop an unsupervised method and checking label is just to be sure about the method accuracy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you plot the data? What do the false positives look like on the plot? How did you select the threshold (n*MAD) that flags an outlier?